# Decrement index in a loop after Swift C-style loops deprecated

Tags: swift, for-loop, decrement

How would you express a decrementing indexed loop in Swift 3.0, where the syntax below is not valid any more?

```
for var index = 10 ; index > 0; index-=1{
   print(index)
}

// 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is an easier (and more Swifty) approach.

```
for i in (0 ..< 5).reversed() {
    print(i) // 4,3,2,1,0
}

let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
for element in array.reversed() {
    print(element) // e,d,c,b,a
}

array.reversed().forEach { print($0) } // e,d,c,b,a

print(Array(array.reversed())) // e,d,c,b,a
```

Answer (score 50):

C-style loops with a fixed increment or decrement can be replaced
by [`stride()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Strideable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/Strideable/s:FeRq_Ss10Strideable_SsS_6strideuRq_S__Fq_FT2toq_2byqq_S_6Stride_GVSs8StrideToq__):

```
for index in 10.stride(to: 0, by: -1) {
    print(index)
}

// 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Use `stride(to: ...)` or `stride(through: ...)` depending on whether
the last element should be included or not.

*This is for Swift 2. The syntax changed (again) for Swift 3, see
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37831159/1187415).*

Answer (score 33):

From `swift 3.0`, The `stride(to:by:)` method on Strideable has been replaced with a free function, `stride(from:to:by:)`

```
for index in stride(from: 10, to: 0, by: -1) {
    print(index)
}

// You can also use stride condition like
// {Some Value}.stride(to: 0, by: -1)
// for index in 10.stride(to: 0, by: -1) { }
```

Comment: This is the way it was in Swift 1. What old is new again!

Comment: Why not just keep the classic C-Style loop, this is like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I think Apple needed Swift flavour everywhere thats why they are reinventing everything in to Swift.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `stride` method:

```
10.stride(through: 0, by: -1).forEach { print($0) }
```

or classic while loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use this C-style loop, here is what you need:

```
let x = 10

infix operator ..> { associativity left }
func ..>(left: Int, right: Int) -> StrideTo<Int> {
    return stride(from: left, to: right, by: -1)
}

for i in x..>0 {
    print(i)
}
```