# #warning: C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I just download a new Xcode (7.3) with swift 2.2.

It has a warning:

> C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift.

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: dont use c-style for loops to fix... :P since its basically saying your code *will* break in the future, so why delay the inevitable. use `for i in 0...10 { }` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213333/swift-3-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of [Replacement for C-style loop in Swift 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166907/replacement-for-c-style-loop-in-swift-2-2) - that is for special cases where the new style cannot accurately replicate the functionality.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Removing `for init; comparison; increment {}` and also remove `++` and `--` easily. and use Swift's pretty for-in loop

```
   // WARNING: C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift
   for var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1 {
      print("I'm number \(i)")
   }
```

---

**Swift 2.2:**

```
   // new swift style works well
   for i in 1...10 {
      print("I'm number \(i)")
   }
```

---

**For decrement index**

```
  for index in 10.stride(to: 0, by: -1) {
      print(index)
  }
```

Or you can use `reverse()` like

```
  for index in (0 ..< 10).reverse() { ... }
```

---

**for float type  `(there is no need to define any types to index)`**

```
 for index in 0.stride(to: 0.6, by: 0.1) {
     print(index)  //0.0 ,0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5
 }
```

---

**Swift 3.0:**

**From `Swift3.0`, The `stride(to:by:)` method on Strideable has been replaced with a free function, `stride(from:to:by:)`**

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 1){
    print(i)
}
```

For decrement index in `Swift 3.0`, you can use `reversed()`

```
for i in (0 ..< 5).reversed() {
    print(i) // 4,3,2,1,0
}
```

[image]

---

Other then `for each` and `stride()`, you can use `While Loops`

```
var i = 0
while i < 10 {
    i += 1
    print(i)
}
```

*`Repeat-While Loop:`*

```
var a = 0
repeat {
   a += 1
   print(a)
} while a < 10
```

check out Control flows in [The Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120)

Comment: This style we can but if we want to loop from array and if that array have zero value it happen crash

Comment: @sony: See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36167115/4573247) for alternatives to the C-style loop, which allows for arrays of zero length (without needing additional if statements).

Comment: yes got it ... but it gives you solution `i in <max(0,foo.count-1)`

Comment: @ElCaptain: Yes there's a few ways to circumvent looping over the members of an array that might be zero, the `max(...)` solution, or `.forEach{ ... }`, or `from.stride(to:by)` etc. Happy to help.

Comment: @EICaptain: How to use this with CGFloat? Until now it was possible to set a type for the index.

Answer (score 4):

For this kind "for" loop:

```
for var i = 10; i >= 0; --i {
   print(i)
}
```

You can write:

```
for i in (0...10).reverse() {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error with this code:

```
for (var i = 1; i != video.getAll().count; i++) {
    print("show number \(i)")
}
```

When you try to fix it with Xcode you get no luck... So you need to use the new swift style (for in loop):

```
for i in 1...video.getAll().count {
    print("show number \(i)")
}
```

Comment: how to use for decrement?

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Use this instead

```
if(myarr.count)
{
    for i in 1...myarr?.count {
      print(" number is \(i)")
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use for decrement?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032182/swift-c-style-loops-deprecated-decrement-index

Comment: @sony `for i in myarr.count.stride(to: 0, by: -1) { ... }`