# Fix warning "C-style for Statement is deprecated" in Swift 3

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift2, compiler-warnings

I have update `Xcode` to 7.3 and now I have a warning to the function that I use to create random strings.

I have tried to change the `for` statement with  `for (i in 0 ..< len){...}` however, the warning became an error.

How can I remove the warning?

```
static func randomStringWithLength (len : Int) -> NSString {
  let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  let randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: len)

  for (var i=0; i < len; i += 1){ // warning
    let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
    randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
  }
  return randomString
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173379/warning-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-ve/36173489

Answer (score 80, accepted):

C-style `for` loop has been deprecated in Swift 3. You can continue using it for a while, but they will certainly disappear in the future.

You can rewrite your loop to Swift's style:

```
for i in 0..<len {
    let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
    randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
}
```

Since you don't use `i` at all in the loop's body, you can replace it with:

```
for _ in 0..<len {
    // do stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 28):

This [BLOG](http://bjmiller.me/post/137624096422/on-c-style-for-loops-removed-from-swift-3) saved my life.

**INCREMENTING**

```
for i in 0 ..< len {

}
```

**DECREMENTING**

```
for i in (0 ..< len).reverse() {

}
```

**NON-SEQUENTIAL INDEXING**

Using where

```
for i in (0 ..< len) where i % 2 == 0 {

}
```

Using striding to or through

```
for i in 0.stride(to: len, by: 2) {

}
```

Comment: You should definitely avoid using a `where` clause in a situation where there is such a clear cut pattern. `0.stride(to: len, by: 2)` halves the number of jumps the processor has to do.

Comment: when I try the last one I get `value of type 'Int' has no member 'stride'`

Answer (score 13):

in Swift 3 it's been an error

some general replacement was posted and just add

**For Swift 3 and need to change the "index"**

```
for var index in stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 1){}
```

Comment: it did worked 4 changing the index , seems not work for now :( 4 Changing the index maybe we should replace for loop with a while loop :( like ` var index = 0
        while(index < len)`

Comment: i try this solution but i keep give a warning that idex is never mutated so you should use let instead of var ,but you can't use let in mutate case

Comment: @AmrAngry just   `for index in stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 1){}` :)

Answer (score 6):

I've had success with the following.  You can use the for loop as follows - note that the for loop is inclusive so you may need to check that len is actually greater than 0:

```
for i in 0...len - 1 {
  let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
  let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
  randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
}
```

Or you can use this:

```
for i in 0 ..< len {
  let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
  let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
  randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
}
```

BTW it appears XCode 7.x *does* help you to get there but it's a two step process.  First you have to change your increment operator from (say) i++ to i += 1 and then XCode warning helps you modify the loop.