# c-style for statement deprecated with a twist

Tags: swift, for-loop, compiler-warnings, deprecated

I've been coding for about 2 years, but I am still terrible at it. Any help would be much appreciated. I have been using the following code to set my background image parameters, after updating to Xcode 7.3 I got the warning 'C-Style statement is deprecated and will be removed':

```
for var totalHeight:CGFloat = 0; totalHeight < 2.0 * Configurations.sharedInstance.heightGame; totalHeight = totalHeight + backgroundImage.size.height  {...}
```

Just to clarify, I have looked at a few other solutions/examples, I have noticed that one workaround is to use the for in loop, however, I just can't seem to wrap my head around this one and everything I have tried does not seem to work. Again, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The question was originally marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213333/fix-warning-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-in-swift-3 but the answer given there will only;y work for simple incrementing fly 1 for loops

Comment: The OP is perfectly right. C-style for loops can do a lot of cool, convenient things that cannot readily be reproduced by any kind of for loop in Swift. In my view, taking C-style for loops away from Swift was terribly ill-advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be best to go with a while loop:

```
var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0
while totalHeight < 2.0 * Configurations.sharedInstance.heightGame {
    // Loop code goes here

    totalHeight += backgroundImage.size.height
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a pity, but keeping in mind that a for loop can _always_ be unrolled into a while loop is often the best way to solve this. It isn't elegant, but it gets the job done.

Comment: This worked, @Slayter. Using the while loop as a workaround did not cross my mind. I think I was too tired. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A strategy that always works is to convert your `for` loop into a `while` loop along the lines of this pattern:

```
for a; b; c {
  // do stuff
}

// can be written as:

a // set up
while b { // condition
  // do stuff
  c // post-loop action 
}
```

So in this case, your `for` loop could be written as:

```
var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0
while totalHeight < 2.0 * Configurations.sharedInstance.heightGame {
  // totalHeight = totalHeight + backgroundImage.size.height can be
  // written slightly more succinctly as:
  totalHeight += backgroundImage.size.height
}
```

But you're right, the preferred solution when possible is to use `for in` instead.

`for in` is a bit different to the C-style `for` or `while`. You don't control the loop variable directly yourself. Instead, the language will loop over any values produced by a "sequence". A sequence is any type that conforms to a  protocol (`SequenceType`) that can create a generator that will serve that sequence up one by one. Lots of things are sequences – arrays, dictionaries, index ranges.

There's a kind of sequence called a stride that you could use to solve this particular problem using `for in`. Strides are a bit like ranges that increment more flexibly. You specify a "by" value that is the amount to vary by each time around:

```
for totalHeight in 0.stride(to: 2.0 * Configurations.sharedInstance.heightGame,
                            by: backgroundImage.size.height) {

    // use totalHeight just the same as with the C-style for loop

}
```

Note, there are two ways of striding, `to:` (up to but not including, like if you'd used `<`), and `through:` (up to and including, like `<=`).

One of the benefits you get with a `for in` loop is that the loop variable doesn't need to be declared with `var`. Instead, each time around the loop you get a fresh new immutable (i.e. constant) variable, which can help avoid some subtle bugs, especially with closure variable capture.

You still need the `while` form occasionally (for example there's no built-in type that allows you to double a counter each time around), but for much everyday use there's a neat (and hopefully more readable) way of doing it without.