# Replace c style for loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

This is the code and wanna replace loop in my app:

```
func loadVisiblePages() {
            // First, determine which page is currently visible
            let pageWidth = eventScrollView!.frame.size.width
            let page = Int(floor((eventScrollView!.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

            // Work out which pages you want to load
            let firstPage = page - 1
            let lastPage = page + 1

            // Purge anything before the first page
            for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
                purgePage(index)
            }

            // Load pages in our range
            for index in firstPage...lastPage {
                loadPage(index)
            }

            // Purge anything after the last page
            for var index = lastPage+1; index < pageImages.count; index = index + 1 { //++index {
                purgePage(index)
            }
        }
```

**What would be the best and the most neat way to implement this loops in Swift?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173379/warning-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-ve/36173489#36173489

Comment: `for index in 0.stride(to: firstPage, by: 1) {
      print(index)
  }`

Comment: before posting any question you  must google it first.