# how do I convert this for to swift 3

Tags: swift3

How do I convert this for block to swift 3

```
let row = textField.tag
if row >= arrayOfLinks.count {
   for var addRow = arrayOfLinks.count; addRow <= row; addRow += 1 {
       arrayOfLinks.append("")
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173379/warning-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-ve/36173489#36173489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C-style for loop is not needed at all

```
let row = textField.tag
while arrayOfLinks.count <= row {
    arrayOfLinks.append("")
}
```

Comment: Note that the OPs original solution (intentional or not ...) appends a final element also when `arrayOfLinks.count` equals `row`, i.e., equivalent to using `<=` rather than `<` in the `while` loop termination condition above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let row = textField.tag
if row >= arrayOfLinks.count {
   var addRow = arrayOfLinks.count
   while addRow <= row {
       arrayOfLinks.append("")
       addRow += 1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you repeatedly append the same (value) element, you needn't use a loop here, but can simply append a collection to the existing `arrayOfLinks` array:

```
if arrayOfLinks.count <= row {
    arrayOfLinks.append(contentsOf:
        [String](repeating: "", count: row - arrayOfLinks.count + 1))
}
```

This should also be more performant than repeatedly appending (same value) elements, not that this should be an issue, however.

Note also that (as per your original solution), a `row` value of e.g. `10` will yield a total (existing + new) of `11` elements in the `numberOfEntries` array.