# How to change old version code to newest version swift ios code

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift3

I want change this code

```
for (var i = tableView(self.tableView , numberOfRowsInSection: 0) - 1; i>0; i-=1 ) {
     tableViewHeight = height + tableView(self.tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0) )
}
```

to Swift. I got an error at *for*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrement index in a loop after Swift C-style loops deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032182/decrement-index-in-a-loop-after-swift-c-style-loops-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this model as reference and migrate your code:

```
for i in (0..<count).reversed() {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: for i in (0...tableView(self.tableView , numberOfRowsInSection: 0) - 1).reversed()
        {
           
        }

Comment: @user7345006, instead of `a ... (b - 1)` use `a ..< b`.

Comment: cant use like that..because i have tableView(self.tableView , numberOfRowsInSection: 0)

Comment: @user7345006, can you explain why not? What's the problem?

Comment: @user7345006, `..<` not `...<`, **two dots, not three dots**

Answer (score 0):

In SWIFT 3

```
    let count = tableView(self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) as Int
    for i in (0 ..< count).reversed() {

        tableViewHeight = height + tableView(self.tableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
    }
```